# how to run a scheduler task for every 5 minutes

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am trying to run the task for every 5 minutes using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's scheduleAtFixedRate` but it is running only for the first time, please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MyRestController {
    private RequestValidator validator;
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
    private MyOtherServiceResponse myOtherServiceResponse;

    @Autowired
    public MyRestController(RequestValidator validator, MyOtherServiceResponse myOtherServiceResponse){
        this.validator = validator;
        this.myOtherServiceResponse = myOtherServiceResponse;
        startScheduler();// calling scheduler for the first time to start 
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/getDetails/{prdId}", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<> getProductInfo(@PathVariable(value="prdId") String prdId) {
        long endTime = 0;
        long startTime = 0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if((validator.validateRequest(prdId))== null) {
            ServiceRequest serviceRequest = validator.getServiceRequest();
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            //getThisServiceResponse(serviceRequest, prdId); 
            System.out.println("Service final Time --------------    " + endTime + "  prdId : " + prdId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            errorResponse = validator.validateRequest(prdId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }

    public void startScheduler(){
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> myOtherServiceResponse.getOtherResponse(validator.getServiceRequest(), validator.PRDID), 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

The `startScheduler()` is called by MyController Constructor, but as per the scheduler it should run `getOtherResponse` for every 5 minutes

Comment: Do you know what's the meaning of the last three arguments in the last line ? `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> myOtherServiceResponse.getOtherResponse(validator.getServiceRequest(), validator.PRDID), 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

Comment: If the lambda throws an exception, you probably won't see it, and the task will be cancelled.

Comment: @alfasin yes, 0 is no delay, 2 is to run every two minutes and TimeUnit.MINUTES is to tell the 2 is in minutes, so to run every 5 minutes I have 5 in place of 2

Comment: @DavidEhrmann the lamda didn't through any exception , it worked for the first time

Comment: @alfasin I used 2 for testing purpose just to reduce wait time for me to test this scheduler. I have replaced 2 with 5 in my question. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: It still could have thrown an exception the second time.

Comment: I'm surprised `myOtherServiceResponse` and `validator` didn't have to be final. I know there's the "effective final" thing, but when it's a member variable, it isn't nearly as safe as a local variable. It also makes it weird that changing a variable from `private` to `protected` could break compilation.

Comment: Is it possible MyRestController is never constructed and you're seeing someone else call getOtherResponse?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Thanks a lot for your time, the only way I am making call to getOtherResponse is from scheduler

Comment: Try this: replace your lambda with `() -> System.err.printf("Executor running at %d%n", System.currentTimeMillis)` and lower the 5 minutes to something like 10 seconds. Does it get called every 10s?

Comment: Also, can you distill this down to a minimally reproducible example? We're left guessing a parts, here.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann sincere apologies for wasting your time, you are correct at the first time it self `If the lambda throws an exception, you probably won't see it, and the task will be cancelled` while digging it deeply found one method was not handled for the exceptions. Fixed the issue by handling exceptions in all method calls. Really appreciate your help and sincere apologies once again